# Seaborn writes to incorrect subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to make multiple plots in one figure and have identified a bug where `axS[i] = sns.boxplot(plot)` causes Seaborn to select the last subplot, as if it forgets the value of `i`. Notice the placement of the print statements and the pointers to the subplot--they should match, but the `sns.boxplot` line messes them up.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(fold+file,index_col=1)
print(df.columns)
types = ['all cells','1 endothelial','2 immune','3 tumor','4 active fibroblast','5 stromal']
fig,axS = plt.subplots(6,1,sharex=True,figsize=(20,8))
for i,ty in enumerate(types):
    
    if i == 0:
        plot = df.loc[:,bioms]
    else:
        key = df.loc[:,'SVM_primary'] == ty
        sdf = df.loc[key,bioms]
        plot = sdf
    print('\n',i,ty)
    print(axS[i])               #First important print statement
    axS[i] = sns.boxplot(plot)
    print(axS[i])               #Second: should be identical, but it's not!
    axS[i].title.set_text(ty)                  
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
0 all cells

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.77;0.775x0.11)

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)


 1 1 endothelial

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.638;0.775x0.11)    # 

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)     # this pointer should be the same as the one above it


 2 2 immune

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.506;0.775x0.11)

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)


 3 3 tumor

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.374;0.775x0.11)

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)


 4 4 active fibroblast

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.242;0.775x0.11)

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)


 5 5 stromal

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.11)
```

The script correctly identifies `i` but in the two `print(axS[i])` statements, the first correctly identifies a unique pointer to a new subplot, then after calling the SNS plot, it thinks it's the last subplot (as if `i` becomes 5 every time `sns.boxplot` is called). I hope I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug with seaborn, this is a misunderstanding of how seaborn works (and a bit of misunderstanding with python in general).

Starting with the general misunderstanding. Say you have a list.

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

If you index it and change the value, you update the list.

```py
x[1] = 5
print(x) # [1, 5, 3]
```

So, when you call `sns.boxplot`, it returns an axis object, which you use to overwrite `axS[i]`.

When you call `sns.boxplot`, you are not telling seaborn which axis to use, so by default it will use the last axis of the most recent figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
y1 = x**2
y2 = np.sin(x)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
a = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y1)
```

[image]

See how it used the last axis of the figure? And I saved the return to `a`, which I can check is equal to the last axis.

```py
print(a == axes[-1])  # True
```

To plot in the correct axis, you have to pass it as a keyword argument to seaborn.

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
a = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y1, ax=axes[0])
b = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y2, ax=axes[1])
```

[image]

And as a check:

```py
print(a == axes[0])  # True
print(b == axes[1])  # True
```

So, in conclusion, pass the axes to the boxplot call and do not overwrite your axes list with the returns (though it won't do anything once you plot to the correct axis).

```py
sns.boxplot(plot, ax=axS[i])
```

Comment: Thank you! Pertaining to the 'general misunderstanding,' if this were normal python, shouldn't the plot be written onto the specified axis instead of picking a different axis? If I write List[2] = sns.boxplot() that should write the plot to the #2 index in the list, no? But thanks, problem solved.

Comment: What do you mean by _"if this were normal python"_? Doing that does save the value to index 2 of the list.

Comment: In the seaborn case, if I use ax[0] = a; ax[1] = b they're both written to ax[1] (this was the problem). In "normal python," i.e. if ax were a list, ax[0] = a; ax[1] = b results in ax = [a,b] (not written to the same location).

Comment: Ah, maybe you think the original code is re-writing for the same value of i? This isn't the case: each 'i' is used once; it first accesses ax[0] then ax[1] then ax[2] but after trying to write each, it's apparent that it wrote to ax[5] regardless of what i was (visible in the printed output). This solves the problem: sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y1, ax=axes[0])]. Thx!

Comment: No, the issue is that you keep setting the value of `axS[i]` with the `Axes` object that `sns.boxplot` is plotting to, it has nothing to do with `i` (which is correct). Because you don't give it an axis to use, it defaults to the last axis. So, you keep overwriting `axS[i]` with the last axis. You should not be setting the value of `axS[i]`, you should only be passing it to `sns.boxplot` so it knows where to plot to.